# Javascript redirecting to wrong page

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I'm creating a simple 1 question multiple choice quiz and depending on the answer submitted I want it to redirect the user to a corresponding page. However, my problem is that no matter what input I submit I'm directed to the same page even if I submit the correct answer. Can someone scan through my code to see if maybe its a slight syntax error that I'm missing.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//w3c//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>International Business</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .myIndent{
            margin-left: 2em;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function submitQuestion(){
            var response = document.getElementById('answer').value;
            if (response == 'C'){
                location="correct.html";
            } else {
                location="wrong.html";
            }
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <p>31.) As long as international businesses _________, Islamic countries are likely to be receptive to those businesses.</p>
        <div class="myIndent">
            <label>A.)<input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer" value="A">employ Muslim people</label><br />
            <label>B.)<input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer" value="B">have property in an Islamic nation<label><br />
            <label>C.)<input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer" value="C">behave in a manner that is consistent with Islamic ethics</label><br />
            <label>D.)<input type="radio" name="answer" id="answer" value="D">adhere to Islamic beliefs</label><br />
        </div>
        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return submitQuestion()">
        <input type="reset" value="Cancel">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: even when I change the line `if(response=='C')` to `if(response=="C")` i still have the same problem

Comment: Try changing "location=" with "location.href=".

Comment: Nope, it still directs me to wrong.html even when I select 'C' when 'C' is the correct answer. It always sends me to wrong.html

Comment: `document.getElementById` gets only first element. Repeat ids is wrong with html elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Label A.), `<labe>` should be `<label>`

On Label B.) you don't have a closing `</label>` tag

You can't have multiple elements with the same ID "answer"

Try something like this:

```
function submitQuestion() {
    var response = document.getElementsByName('answer');
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        if (response[i].checked) {
            response = response[i].value;
        }
    }
    if (response == 'C') {
        location = "correct.html";
    }
    else {
        location = "wrong.html";
    }
    return false;
}
```

This function gets all of the elements with the name "answer" in the radio group.  Then checks if the correct one is selected.

Here is the complete code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>International Business</title>
<style type="text/css">
.myIndent{
margin-left: 2em;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitQuestion() {
        var response = document.getElementsByName('answer');
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            if (response[i].checked) {
                response = response[i].value;
            }
        }
        if (response == 'C') {
            location = "correct.html";
        }
        else {
            location = "wrong.html";
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<p>31.) As long as international businesses _________, Islamic countries are likely to be receptive to those businesses.</p>
<div class="myIndent">
<label>A.)<input type="radio" name="answer" id="answerA" value="A" />employ Muslim people</label><br />
<label>B.)<input type="radio" name="answer" id="answerB" value="B" />have property in an Islamic nation</label><br />
<label>C.)<input type="radio" name="answer" id="answerC" value="C" />behave in a manner that is consistent with Islamic ethics</label><br />
<label>D.)<input type="radio" name="answer" id="answerD" value="D" />adhere to Islamic beliefs</label><br />
</div>
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return submitQuestion()">
<input type="reset" value="Cancel">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only have 1 ID. `document.getElementById('answer');` will get the first element it comes to.

#### Advice

Unless your students are in elementary school, I cannot advise that you should write a quiz like this; unless its more of an exercise to learn the right answer.  If it's grading based on regurgitation, then there are too many ways for someone to *happen upon* the answer without having to read the question.

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/44gak58h/)

```
function submitQuestion() {
    var possible_answers = document.getElementsByName('answer');
    var selection;
    for (var i=0,n=possible_answers.length; i<n; i++){
        if(possible_answers[i].checked === true){
            selection = possible_answers[i].value;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (selection == 'C') {
        window.location = "correct.html";
    } else {
        window.location = "wrong.html";
    }
    return false;
}
```

#### Fixed HTML Syntax:

```
<form>
    <p>31.) As long as international businesses _________, Islamic countries are likely to be receptive to those businesses.</p>
    <div class="myIndent">
        <label>A.)<input type="radio" name="answer" value="A" />employ Muslim people</label>
        <label>B.)<input type="radio" name="answer" value="B" />have property in an Islamic nation</label>
        <label>C.)<input type="radio" name="answer" value="C" />behave in a manner that is consistent with Islamic ethics</label>
        <label>D.)<input type="radio" name="answer" value="D" />adhere to Islamic beliefs</label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return submitQuestion();">
    <input type="reset" value="Cancel">
</form>
```

#### A little more CSS:

```
.myIndent {
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.myIndent label {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way I can edit this to account for all 4 elements using the same ID? As I do not wish to declare 4 variables and then check them all.

Comment: Don't use the ID attribute at all.

Comment: This is correct, however, there are additional errors that should be corrected as well.  Also, it may be helpful to explain how to get the value of the checked radio button.  See my answer for more of an explanation.

Comment: @HowardRenollet I was in the middle of creating a fiddle :)

Comment: @vol7ron, I'll give u a +1 since your answer was technically correct.  The edit definitely makes it more valuable to the op now :)

Comment: @HowardRenollet yeah, we all reached the same.  My intent was first to answer why, then take the time to give an example of the correct way, which I was working on and it turns out you all beat me to :)  Nice work.

Comment: @RyanSisson see the modifications to the HTML and CSS, which reduces the need for things like `<br />`

Comment: The purpose of the quiz is more for a presentation. In one of my business classes we were given an old exam question and asked to answer it then present it to the class. I figured since I had interest in web development I wouldnt do a boring/easy powerpoint, so I decided on this to give me some practice, and learn new things I was unaware of.

Comment: Thats good. Presentation software in general could use revamping. It lacks the dynamic interactions that many good presentations require. HTML-based presentations are pretty common for that reason. Nice work.

Answer (score 0):

Use class instead of id

```
<div class="myIndent">
<labe>A.)<input type="radio" name="answer" class="answer" value="A">employ Muslim people</label><br />
<label>B.)<input type="radio" name="answer" class="answer" value="B">have property in an Islamic nation<label><br />
<label>C.)<input type="radio" name="answer" class="answer" value="C">behave in a manner that is consistent with Islamic ethics</label><br />
<label>D.)<input type="radio" name="answer" class="answer" value="D">adhere to Islamic beliefs</label><br />
</div>
```

However, you dont need to even give a class to all. Get checked radio button by name

```
var response = document.getElementsByName('answer').checked;
```

Comment: With this change, the form no longer redirects.

Comment: @RyanSisson : Oh yes it should be document.getElemenstByName. Let me edit

Comment: Thank you! However I saw Howard's answer before I got to your edit, but this was still helpful.